# Error Type ConcreteSet must be convertible to BaseSet<BaseItem>

Tags: c#, derived-class

I have created both abstract classes: `BaseSet` and `BaseItem` which is parent for `ConcreteSet`

```
public class BaseItem { }
public class ConcreteItem { } : BaseItem
public class BaseSet<T> where T : BaseItem { }
public class ConcreteSet : BaseSet<ConcreteItem> { }
```

Now I have created manager that have dynamic type of `BaseSet<BaseItem>`

```
public abstract class BaseSetManager<T> : PersistentSingleton<BaseSetManager<T>>
where T : BaseSet<BaseItem>
```

Next when I try to derive this manager with:

```
public sealed class ConcreteSetManager : BaseSetManager<ConcreteSet>
```

I get fallowing error `The type 'ConcreteSet' must be convertible to 'BaseSet<BaseItem>' in order to use it as parameter 'T' in generic class 'BaseSetManager'`

Is there any way to keep abstraction like this, or I have to give-up on abstraction and move back to base general type.

I'm Using Unity3D which doesn't support covariance (C# 3.0)

Comment: Are you confused about why `ConcreteSet` (which is a `BaseSet<ConcreteItem>`) is not assignable where a `BaseSet<BaseItem>` is expected? It's because `BaseSet` is not covariant.

Comment: So is there any method to make `BaseSet` covariant?

Comment: Yes, you can extract an interface from `BaseSet` and mark the parameter `T` in this interface as covariant. Of course, this assumes you are actually using `T` covariantly, i.e. in "read" positions.

Comment: @AsadSaeeduddin Sadly I don't have the way to introduce this since I'm limited to C# version 3. But I have found the way around which I will add as the answer for right now.

Comment: I could just tell you the magic keywords to add, but you'd immediately run into trouble unless you understand what variance actually is. You should take a look at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/covariance-contravariance/

Answer (score 2):

The only way for me right now since I'm limited to C# 3 is to use multiple Types in BaseSetManager. Better ideas still appreciated.

```
public abstract class BaseSetManager<T, P> : PersistentSingleton<BaseSetManager<T, P>>
where T : BaseSet<P>
where P : BaseItem

public sealed class ConcreteSetManager : BaseSetManager<ConcreteSet, ConcreteItem>
```

If you are looking for an answer with higher language target find comments in question from @AsadSaeeduddin